# Css Full Width and Scroll Bar issue

Tags: css, wordpress, html, width

[My website](http://www.animefushigi.com)

style css can be found [here](http://pasteit.com/158)

I'm looking at my website on firefox, and I notice that the site is not stretching to the full width. You can tell by maximizing the page and then looking at the menu at the top right.

Also, there seems to be a horizontal scroll bar at all times which I don't need unless the site is showing the full content area in the middle.

Any suggestions on how I can fix?

Comment: Your css is over 1700 lines long and your site has multiple nested divs. It would help if you tried removed everything that's not directly related to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the horizontal scroll bar, try the following:

On **DIV** `#master_wrapper` remove:

```
float:left;
width:100%;
```

And add

```
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 auto;
```

On **DIV** `#outer_wrapper` remove:

```
float:left;
width:100%;
```

And add

```
overflow:hidden;
```

The site seems to go full width on Chrome ok.

Comment: Check the code, there is a semicolon in both `overflow;hidden;`

Comment: Seems to have fixed both my problems. Thank you